# Python program that obfuscates an email address

Tags: python, html, email, escaping

I decided to resume my (limited) Python skills after not coding for a long time.

Here's a very simple self-contained program to convert the characters of an email address into their HTML entities (the purpose is to make the email invisible to spamrobots).

- Any comment for improvement? (e.g. args parsing, code style, etc.)
- Apart from the `-h` option in `argparse`, what is the standard way to add some documentation for it, such as a manpage or some embedded help?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#
# mung - Convert a string into its HTML entities
#


import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Convert a string into its HTML entities.')
parser.add_argument('string_to_mung', help = 'String to convert')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--link', action = 'store_true', help = 'Embed the munged string into a mailto: link')
args = parser.parse_args()


def mung(plain):
    munged = ''
    for c in plain:
        munged = munged + '&#' + str(ord(c)) + ';'
    return munged


string_munged = mung(args.string_to_mung)

if (args.link):
    print('<a href="&#109;&#97;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#111;&#58;')
    print(string_munged + '">')
    print(string_munged + '</a>')
else:
    print(string_munged)
```

Comment: Spam bots deal rather well with X(HT)ML escape sequences since they often use appropriate parser libraries.

Comment: Actually my experience suggests otherwise, as an obfuscated email address gets ten times less spam; see https://bit.ly/2UOuAOA

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code is straightforward and reads well, but:

1. string concatenation is not very efficient, especially in a loop. You'd be better off using `str.join` on an iterable;
2. encoding the `mailto:` part yourself impairs readability and maintenance, if only you had a function to do it for you. Oh wait...
3. The comment at the beginning would be better as a module docstrings, you would then be able to use it as the `argparse` description using `__doc__`;
4. You should avoid interleaving code and function definition, and protect top level code using an [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/5069029) guard.

Proposed improvements:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

"""Convert a string into its HTML entities"""


import argparse


def command_line_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=__doc__)
    parser.add_argument('string_to_mung', help='String to convert')
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--link', action='store_true',
                        help='Embed the munged string into a mailto: link')
    return parser


def mung(plain):
    return ''.join('&#{};'.format(ord(c)) for c in plain)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = command_line_parser().parse_args()
    string_munged = mung(args.string_to_mung)
    if (args.link):
        string_munged = '<a href="{0}{1}">{1}</a>'.format(mung('mailto:'), string_munged)
    print(string_munged)
```

Comment: Python 3.6+: `'&#{};'.format(ord(c))` → `f'&#{ord(c)};'`

Comment: @RomanOdaisky Given that there is no version tag, I prefer to keep `format`.